# What is the Bootstrap3 approach to long data tables without repeating headers titles?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, documentation, html-table

HTML tables with system commands run long, as seen here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora

Is there a Bootstrap3 way to make tables like these responsive, keeping the wide appearance for desktop and creating a mobile appearance that carries the context of the action and the OS vendor for each command without requiring scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Contextual classes` for styling bootstrap table row:

```
<tr class="active">...</tr>
<tr class="success">...</tr>
<tr class="warning">...</tr>
<tr class="danger">...</tr>
<tr class="info">...</tr>
```

also, you can use non-standart `thead` repeating, not highly recommended but workes:

```
<table>
    <thead> ... </thead>
    <tbody> ... </tbody>
    <thead> ... </thead>
    <tbody> ... </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I wasn't looking for tips on how to deal with "Package File Information" (the sectional headers) so much as "Extract files in a package", the wide sub-items.  This page is not responsive.  If it were what would happen to lines like:

(task) Extract files in a package 
(redhat) rpm2cpio package.rpm | cpio -vid 
(ubuntu) dpkg-deb --extract package.deb dir-to-extract-to